# Is there a programmatical way to get Google Earth imagery dates for specific coordinates?

Tags: date, gis, google-earth

I need to cite about 400 imagery locations in Google Earth for a project using this citation model: https://sites.google.com/a/tas.tw/mscitation/how/ge. This requires that I have the imagery date for each location (handily stored in a KML.  Unfortunately for me, I didn't know that I needed this when I initially created the KML placemarks. Is there a way to extract the imagery date somehow based on either the KML or the placemark coordinates? If I could get a KML file that shows imagery coverage by date, that would be sufficient. I am a GIS Specialist and could easily convert the KML to a shapefile in ArcGIS and do a simple location query to get the dates. I haven't been able to locate any such KML, however. Otherwise, I'll have to revisit each placemark and manually copy over the imagery date from the information bar in GE. Not a huge deal (I have already done that for about a quarter of them), but it occurred to me that there may be an easier (and quicker) way to do this in an automated fashion.

It seems like this may be helpful for anyone that needs to cite hundreds or thousands of Google Earth locations. I doubt this will be the last time I need to do this, as well.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need the dates (like 1.2.2012) of when the particular images below your locations where taken / updated by Google?

From within GoogleEarth, I do not see a chance other then doing this manually for each of your bookmarks. There is simply no scripting capability.

As a chance, you might want to look at the GoogleEarth-plugin (Windows and MacOS only) for web-browsers. It has a javascript-API, which is documented here: https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_g_e_plugin 
Maybe digging deep in here ... solves your problem.

One last note: GoogleMaps also has an API, but the imagery sometimes differs with respect to GoogleEarth.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into the plugin and GoogleMaps API, and see what I can find. I'll post a solution if I find one.